# Standard Python Auth0 project does not seem to authenticate

Tags: python, oauth, flask, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am trying to run a standard Python Auth0 project [available here](https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/python)
If you are logged in it comes with valid pre-generated keys in .env file and I checked them anyway, so question is similar to [Django + Auth0 JWT authentication refusing to decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426066/django-auth0-jwt-authentication-refusing-to-decode) but answers there do not help.

server.py from example:

```
import jwt
import base64
import os

from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, _request_ctx_stack
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
from dotenv import Dotenv
from flask.ext.cors import cross_origin

env = None

try:
    env = Dotenv('./.env')
    client_id = env["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = env["AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"]
except IOError:
  env = os.environ

app = Flask(__name__)

# Format error response and append status code.
def handle_error(error, status_code):
  resp = jsonify(error)
  resp.status_code = status_code
  return resp

def requires_auth(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)
    if not auth:
      return handle_error({'code': 'authorization_header_missing', 'description': 'Authorization header is expected'}, 401)

    parts = auth.split()

    if parts[0].lower() != 'bearer':
      return handle_error({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description': 'Authorization header must start with Bearer'}, 401)
    elif len(parts) == 1:
      return handle_error({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description': 'Token not found'}, 401)
    elif len(parts) > 2:
      return handle_error({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description': 'Authorization header must be Bearer + \s + token'}, 401)

    token = parts[1]
    try:
    payload = jwt.decode(
        token,
        base64.b64decode(client_secret.replace("_","/").replace("-","+")),
        audience=client_id
    )
    except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
    return handle_error({'code': 'token_expired', 'description': 'token is expired'}, 401)
    except jwt.InvalidAudienceError:
    return handle_error({'code': 'invalid_audience', 'description': 'incorrect audience, expected: ' + client_id}, 401)
    except jwt.DecodeError:
    return handle_error({'code': 'token_invalid_signature', 'description': 'token signature is invalid'}, 401)
    except Exception:
    return handle_error({'code': 'invalid_header', 'description':'Unable to parse authentication token.'}, 400)

    _request_ctx_stack.top.current_user = user = payload
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  return decorated

# Controllers API
@app.route("/ping")
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
def ping():
    return "All good. You don't need to be authenticated to call this"

@app.route("/secured/ping")
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
@cross_origin(headers=['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'])
@requires_auth
def securedPing():
    return "All good. You only get this message if you're authenticated"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3001)))
```

http://localhost:3001/secured/ping gives:

```
{
  "code": "authorization_header_missing", 
  "description": "Authorization header is expected"
}
```

Headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3001/secured/ping
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 UNAUTHORIZED
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3001

Response Headers
Content-Length:98
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 15 Jun 2016 13:15:57 GMT
Server:Werkzeug/0.11.4 Python/2.7.6

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3001
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/50.0.2661.102 Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: But there is no `Authorization` header in the `Request Headers` so what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Correct. Here is a standard example from Auth0. How to make change this code sample to make it sending Authorization header?

Answer (score 1):

In the document you linked under the section [Call Your API](https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/python#4-call-your-api) the request is done with the header `Authorization` for example if you need to connect with curl use the following option:

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ID_TOKEN_HERE'
```

This `Authorization` header is then parsed by your python code.

But as you can see in your supplied `Request Headers` there is no `Authorization` field in the header.

Also, the code sample is not sending any requests but rather serving them, so no changes to the code must be made.

Rather, to request the secured version of ping, you need to request it with one of the methods described in the linked document. Accessing the secured page in a browser is not possible without javascript.

Comment: OK. Then where do I find an Auth0 example which redirects to log in page if there is no authorisation?

Comment: Replace the `return handle_error({'code': 'authorization_header_missing...` line with `return redirect(url_for('login'))` and create a new route named `login`. Please read the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/) as this has nothing to do with AuthO and the asked question.